# Slick carousel formatting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the slick carousel http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and I have ran into a problem where I can't manage to format the carousel so it is displayed properly on my page. Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

…and I want it to look like the demo:

[image]

My HTML for it is:

```
<div id='slickcontrol'>
<div class="slick">
  <div><img class='slickimage' src='images/choice1small.jpg'/></div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried setting this as the css for `.slickcontrol`:

```
#slickcontrol{
width:400px;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
}
```

but to no avail. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you attaching slick to `.slick` and not `#slickcontrol`? Also try removing `position:relative;` from `#slickcontrol`.

```
#slickcontrol{
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slick').slick({
    setting-name: setting-value
  });
});
```

Comment: hi, yes i attached to slick. Removing position:relative didn't help either :(

Answer (score 0):

Is that a screen shot of what it looks like?

Two thoughts. One:
It looks like the javascript isn't loading or you don't have the right jquery version

Per the makers web site..

```
Add slick.js before your closing <body> tag, after jQuery (requires jQuery 1.7 +)
```

Two:
If you are just trying to get the image centered nicely inside its container, I added a few simple lines to your css...

http://jsfiddle.net/g4GKm/